# Meaning of unused space in RAID arrays

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm using the hpacucli command line tool to check the raid arrays in my server. What does "SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB" mean?

```
# hpacucli controller all show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50123456119ABCDE)

  array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

     logicaldrive 1 (136.7 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
     physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
     physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
     physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
     physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you've allocated the full amount of drive space available to the array in logical drives.

HP Smart Array controllers have the concept of Arrays (physical groups of disks) and Logical Drives (virtual RAID groups that live on the Array).

You can have Logical Drives smaller than an Array, or multiple Logical Drives contained within an Array. You can even have Logical Drives of different RAID protection schemes (e.g. RAID 5 or RAID 1+0) in an Array.

What the 0MB Unused Space means is exactly that. You don't have any unused space, or plainly, you've allocated all of the space available on the array.

If you added another physical disk to the array; perhaps another 72GB disk... You would see 72GB unused space.